# How to find the three largest elements of this matrix?

Tags: inequality

I have a matrix with positive real numbers

$$\mathbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix} a & x & y \\ t & b & z\\ u & v & c\end{pmatrix},$$
where I know that $a,b$ and $c$ are the largest elements of $\mathbf{A}$. That is, $a\ge x,y,z,t,u,v$, $b\ge x,y,z,t,u,v$ and $c\ge x,y,z,t,u,v$.

From $\mathbf{A}$, I create a matrix $\mathbf{B}$ as follows:

$$\mathbf{B}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{a}{t+u} & \frac{x}{b+v} & \frac{y}{z+c} \\ \frac{t}{a+u} & \frac{b}{x+v} & \frac{z}{y+c}\\ \frac{u}{a+t} & \frac{v}{x+b} & \frac{c}{y+z}\end{pmatrix},$$

I would like to find the three largest elements of $\mathbf{B}$. I guess they are $\frac{a}{t+u}$, $\frac{b}{x+v}$ and $\frac{c}{y+z}$, but how to prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that every diagonal entry of $\textbf{B}$ is the largest of its respective column. This has nothing to do with linear algebra; it is a matter of working out some elementary inequalities:
$$ \frac{a}{t+u} \geq \frac{t}{t+u} \geq \frac{t}{a+u}. $$
The other inequalities follow in an analogous manner.

However, there is no guarantee that $\frac{a}{t+u}$ should be larger than $\frac{x}{b+v}$. For instance, if we start with
$$\textbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}11 & 10 & 0\\10 & 11 & 10\\10 & 0 & 11\end{pmatrix},$$
then we get
$$\textbf{B} \approx \begin{pmatrix}0.55 & 0.909 & 0\\0.476 & 1.1 & 0.909\\0.476 & 0 & 1.1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you. I did not find any tag that fits with my question. How to show that the diagonal of $\mathbf{B}$ has the largest elementss? I have an $n\times n$ matrix, can I show the same as for $3\times3$?

Comment: To show that a diagonal entry is the largest of its column, you use the estimate I give. First we decrease the numerator and then we increase the denominator, so we end up with a smaller number. Due to symmetry, you essentially only have to prove this one inequality; the other ones are analogous. This also works if you start with an $n \times n$ matrix $\textbf{A} = (a_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^{n \times n}$ and define $\textbf{B} = (b_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ by $$b_{ij} = \frac{a_{ij}}{\displaystyle\sum_{k\neq i} a_{kj}},$$ provided this is well defined (not dividing by zero).

Comment: As far as the tags are concerned: I agree that it's hard to find an appropriate tag for this question. Perhaps "inequality" is the best match?